# Angular - Implementing event handler on button mouseup when mouse is not over the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, frontend

I want to implement a Push To Talk button that enables voice when I mouse down, and disables voice when I release the mouse. Here's the code I have right now:

```
    <button ng-mousedown="enablePushToTalk()" ng-mouseup="disablePushToTalk()" class="btn"> PushToTalk </button>
```

The problem scenario is this:

1. User hits push to talk button (mouseDown: enablePushToTalk is called)
2. User moves mouse away from button
3. User releases mouse: mouseUp event is never called, thus disablePushToTalk is never called! So Push To Talk stays enabled.

Here's a gif:

[image: Buggy behavior]

How do I ensure that "disablePushToTalk" gets called for every time that "enablePushToTalk" is called?

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an `ng-mouseup` event listener to a parent element?

Created a jsBin using above idea for your problem.

**Solution 1:**

//html

```
<body style='height:500px;border:1px solid black;' ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-mouseup='disable()'>
<div >
  <button ng-mousedown="enablePushToTalk()" ng-mouseup="disablePushToTalk()" class="btn"> PushToTalk </button>
</div>
</body>
```

//js

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    var isMouseUp = false;
    $scope.enablePushToTalk = function(){console.log('mouseup');isMouseUp=true;}
    $scope.disablePushToTalk = function(){console.log('mousedown');isMouseUp=false;}
    $scope.disable = function(){if(!isMouseUp) return;console.log('mousedown from body');isMouseUp=false;}
}
```

jsBin link: http://jsbin.com/nedijudaga/edit?html,js,console,output

**Solution 2:**

Adding an `ng-mouseup` event only to parent element and not on `button` would do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to work better (I tried solution 2). But then I ran into a second problem: what if the user mouses up when the mouse is outside of the parent element? For example, if the user releases his mouse outside of the browser window, it doesn't seem like the mouseup event would be registered.

Comment: I got your problem, but does your app requirement allows the user to do that? if not then you trigger (or even alert the user before triggering) mouseup if he leaves browser window

Comment: Thank you, I ended up adding an event heandler on ng-mouseleave to also disable push to talk

Comment: Cool. Keep rocking :)